# jquery plugin filtering form field inputs with regex for decimal/float values - validated regex patterns dont seem to be working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

**Background**: using JQuery plugin for input text field filtering and regex (tried several variations actually) with symfony 3.x

jquery http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input

**Goal**: Have the form field accept only positive float / decimal up to 3 decimal places.

Acceptable:

```
3.24
.56
3456.789
```

Not Acceptable:

```
-3.65
-.67
3.6.5
3c.56
5g
```

I have used reg exp testers such as https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html to build/find a reg ex that works such as;

`^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$`
or
`^[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$`

Both work in the tester.

I am using regex like;

```
$('#name of the form field').filter_input({regex: "^[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$"});
```

They don't seem to work with the jquery plugin. The plugin might be buggy or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the plugin is just accepting character groups, and isn't matching the full pattern. So you can basically just restrict the type of characters that can be inserted, but you can't specify a full pattern that has to be matched.

Here's a quick and dirty solution that won't require an additional plugin:

```
$("#myField").on("keyup change", function () {
    var self = $(this), lastValid = self.data("lastValid") || "";
    if (self.val().match(/^\d*\.?\d{0,3}$/)) {
      self.data("lastValid", self.val());
    } else {
      self.val(lastValid);
    }
});
```

It basically just stores the last valid input and sets the field back to the last valid input once something invalid was entered.

The pattern I'm matching against is: `^\d*\.?\d{0,3}$`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you. No need to use any plugin.
https://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/dtky1okL/

```
<input type="text" id="tester">
<div class="alert"></div>
  $("#tester").on("focusout", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
  var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$");
    if(patt.test(value)){
    $(".alert").text("Match Found!!");

  }else{
    $(".alert").text("No Match Found!!");
  }
});
```